# not able to connect main class with other class in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, class, netbeans-6.9

I am trying to make a gui based application in netbeans but my main class is not connecting to other class.
The code for main class is as below:

```
package legaldiary;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ULogin ulgn = new ULogin();

}
}
```

The code for other class is as below:

```
package legaldiary;
public class ULogin extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public ULogin() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Welcome to Legal Diary");

    jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

    jLabel3.setText("jLabel3");

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

    jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(64, 64, 64)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 172, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 172, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGap(71, 71, 71))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(89, 89, 89)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 174, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(137, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(152, 152, 152)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(175, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(41, 41, 41)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(37, 37, 37)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(57, 57, 57)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(34, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ULogin().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Please help me out in finding the error.

Answer (score 1):

You never call `setVisible` in your `Main` class. Although you do call it in the `main` method of `ULogin` itself, that method is not invoked when running from `Main`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      new ULogin().setVisible(true);
   }
});
```

Comment: Works for me. If you have placed this code in the `Main` class, try clean & rebuild `Shift + F11`.